# VS2008 - Unable to Add Web Reference to Web Application Project (The web services enumeration components are not available)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, asmx

I've run into a situation where I was unable to add a Web Reference in Visual Studio 2008 to a Web Application Project. The error I couldn't resolve was "**The web services enumeration components are not available. You need to reinstall Visual Studio to add web references to your application.**"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should ask this in the form of a regular question then post your own answer below.

Comment: That's an option indeed.

Comment: I've reworded it as a question as asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix for this is to run the following command:

```
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs
```

Source : [Adding Web Service Reference Fails](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/asmxandxml/thread/25c39cb8-eda7-4121-b55f-3182c011372a)